# How to remove all spaces from command output

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script for ssh key need to compare from local to remote. I have the command to check the key but command output result shows line by line. I need to get the output without spaces is there anyway to get output which is I'm expecting.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
$ cat ex.txt
this is an example
this is line 2
```

```sh
$ cat ex.txt |tr -d ' '
thisisanexample
thisisline2
```

```sh
$ cat ex.txt |tr -d '\n'
this is an example this is line 2
```

```sh
$ cat ex.txt |tr -d '\n'' '
thisisanexamplethisisline2
```

tr = translate or delete characters
-d = delete character / characters
'\n' = newlines
' ' = spaces